# Pandasで複数のファイルを結合したい

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasで複数のファイルを結合したいとかんがえております。

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
list = []
for file in csv_files:
    list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
df = pd.concat(list)
df.to_csv(“total.csv”,index=False,encoding="CP932")
```

しかし途中で止まってしまいます。エラーは下記になります。ご指導お願いします。

```
  File "<ipython-input-43-62a2b0e3e6af>", line 20
    df.to_csv(“total.csv”,index=False,encoding="CP932")
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

なお、,encoding="CP932"を外した場合のエラーメッセージは下記になります。

```
  File "<ipython-input-44-826dbe085913>", line 20
    df.to_csv(“total.csv”,index=False)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

さて、ここまででご指導いただき、一歩前進しました。そして次のエラーです。

```
---> 15     list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
```

エラーは長くなりますが、下記になります。

```
~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    450 
    451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    453 
    454     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    934             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    935 
--> 936         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    937 
    938     def close(self):

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1166     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1167         if engine == "c":
-> 1168             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1169         else:
   1170             if engine == "python":

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1996         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1997 
-> 1998         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1999         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2000 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: `df.to_csv()` にエンコーディングを指定していることから(`encoding="CP932"`)、`pd.read_csv()` にも同様に指定すると良いかと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらくそのエラーをとるだけならば、`“`と`”` を `"` に修正すればよいはずです。

つまり `“total.csv”` ではなく `"total.csv"`です。

Comment: 早速ありがとうございます。試したところ、一歩前進しました。